# .Deb package postinst file not appending data to ~/.bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, debian, deb, post-install

I have this very simple postinst file for a .Deb package:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 'alias command_pandora="sudo /usr/local/bin/pandora"' >> ~/.bashrc

echo 'Pandora Storage Server Installation complete.'
```

When I run it I even get the 'Pandora Storage Server Installation complete.' message, but nothing is appended to `~/.bashrc`; nevertheless when I run this command alone in the terminal:

```
echo 'alias command_pandora="sudo /usr/local/bin/pandora"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

It does work. I already tried modifying the file permisions for `~/.bashrc` but still get the same result. I also tried running a separate script with the same content and running it and it also works, so it seems to be related to dpkg.

Why is the content not being appended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `postinst` script runs as `root`. Package installation is a system installation utility; it should absolutely not modify users' private files, including those of `root`.

Tangentially, defining an alias seems like the wrong solution to your problem. Generally, prefer functions or shell scripts over aliases.

If the tool requires privileged access through `sudo`, perhaps refactor it to run itself with `sudo` (maybe with a check to only do this when it is connected to a terminal, to prevent it from hanging when run unattended).

Or, simply, include `/usr/bin/command_pandora` in the package with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec sudo /usr/local/bin/pandora "$@"
```

(Marginally, I suppose it could add something to `/etc/skel/.bashrc` but this will only create a new alias for users which are created after this change, or users whose `.bashrc` presciently run `source /etc/skel/.bashrc`. I don't think that's a good idea, either.)

Comment: Also, your package should definitely not be creating `/usr/local/bin/pandora`. The directory `/usr/local/bin` is for packages which have been installed outside the control of `dpkg`; if your package installs something, it should be in `/usr/bin` (or perhaps `/usr/sbin` for binaries which qualify for this).